# KnockoutJS: How to get a reference to ViewModel when clicking a bound list item

Tags: knockout.js

*How can I get a reference to the root View Model when a bound html list item is clicked?*

I have a ViewModel closure "class" that uses KnockoutJS for binding.

The ViewModel holds a `ko.observableArray` representing each list item in an unordered list.

```
// ViewModel Base
var ViewModel=( function(){

    // ctor
    function ViewModel(data,id){
        // Publics
        this.list=ko.observableArray([{name:'one'},{name:'two'},{name:'three'}]);
        this.selectedItem=ko.observable(null);
    };

    // set "selectedItem" when user clicks an <li>
    ViewModel.prototype.selectItem=function(){

        // below works when using instantiated "vm1"
        vm1.selectedItem(this);

        // correctly reports the name property of the clicked list item
        console.log(vm1.selectedItem().name);
    };

    // Return Publics
    return(ViewModel);

})();

// Build a new view model
var vm1=new ViewModel();

// apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(vm1);
```

The observableArray is bound to an Html unordered list.

Each html list item triggers `.selectItem` in the ViewModel when the list item is clicked.

```
<ul data-bind='foreach:list'>
    <li class='item' data-bind='click: $root.selectItem' >
        <span data-bind='text:name'></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Problem is...**

In `.selectItem` I need to set a `selectedItem` property on the view model instance.

But I don't see a way to get to the view model instance from the `this` that KnockoutJS give to `selectedItem`.

Using the `vm1` instance directly works, but I don't want my generic ViewModel tied to using a hard-coded reference to `vm1`

```
    // set "selectedItem" when user clicks an <li>
    ViewModel.prototype.selectItem=function(){

        // below fails when using "ViewModel" (and numerous other tries by me)
        ViewModel.selectedItem(this);  // error 

        console.log(vm1.selectedItem().name);
    };
```

Snippet:

```js
function log(){console.log.apply(console,arguments);}


// ViewModel Base
var ViewModel=( function(){

  // ctor
  function ViewModel(data,id){
    // Publics
    this.list=ko.observableArray([{name:'one'},{name:'two'},{name:'three'}]);
    this.selectedItem=ko.observable(null);
  };

  // set "selectedItem" when user clicks an <li>
  ViewModel.prototype.selectItem=function(){
    // below works when using specified vm1
    // below fails when using ViewModel.selectedItem(this)
    vm1.selectedItem(this);
    alert('Clicked on: '+vm1.selectedItem().name);
  };

  // Return Publics
  return(ViewModel);

})();

// Build a new view model
var vm1=new ViewModel();

// apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(vm1);
```

```html
<p>Click on a list item.</p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind='foreach:list'>
  <li class='item' data-bind='click: $root.selectItem' >
    <span data-bind='text:name'></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The recommended way of writing methods in your viewmodels](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function) is to define them inside the constructor, not in the prototype, so they operate on that constructed viewmodel:

```
function ViewModel(data,id){
  var that = this;
  // Publics
  this.list = ko.observableArray([{name:'one'},{name:'two'},{name:'three'}]);
  this.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);

  this.selectItem = function(item){
    that.selectedItem(item);
    alert('Clicked on: '+that.selectedItem().name);
  };

}
```

---

Additionally, you should be using `$parent` context, not `$root`, so it works even inside another viewmodel:

```
<ul data-bind='foreach:list'>
  <li class='item' data-bind='click: $parent.selectItem'>
    <span data-bind='text:name'></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see...include `.selectItem` directly in the inside the object rather than on the `object.prototype`. Then `self=this` allows self to be seen in `.selectItem`. Moving .selectItem out of .prototype is a good solution since the few view model objects will cost very little increased overhead. Thanks for an answer that eliminates my "hacky" workaround! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I worked out this way to get a view model reference without having to hard-code the view model instance in the view model "class".

It involves grabbing the browser's event object and using it to get the ViewModel's `$root` through `ko.contextFor(event.target).$root`.

While this works, I'm thinking there must be a simpler way of eliminating the hard-coded reference in the generic ViewModel.

**Any other ideas?**

```
// set "selectedItem" when user clicks an <li>
ViewModel.prototype.selectItem=function(item,event){

    // get a reference to the view model using ko.contextFor
    var theVM=ko.contextFor(event.target).$root;

    // set the "selectedItem" property on the view model
    theVM.selectedItem(this);

     // working!
    alert(vm1.selectedItem().name); 
};
```

```js
// ViewModel Base
var ViewModel=( function(){

  // ctor
  function ViewModel(data,id){
    // Publics
    this.list=ko.observableArray([{name:'one'},{name:'two'},{name:'three'}]);
    this.selectedItem=ko.observable(null);
  };

  // set "selectedItem" when user clicks an <li>
  ViewModel.prototype.selectItem=function(item,event){
    var theVM=ko.contextFor(event.target).$root;
    theVM.selectedItem(this);
    // It works!
    alert(vm1.selectedItem().name);
  };

  // Return Publics
  return(ViewModel);

})();

// Build a new view model
var vm1=new ViewModel();

// apply bindings
ko.applyBindings(vm1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind='foreach:list'>
  <li class='item' data-bind='click: $root.selectItem' >
    <span data-bind='text:name'></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```